# Refinements and namespaces

Tags: ruby, monkeypatching, refinements

Trying to patch net/http and have it only apply to one service class. Refinements seem to be the way to go. The monkey patch below works but the refinement doesn't. Is this a namespace issue? The project is on ruby 2.3.0 but have tried with 2.4.1 as well and only the monkey patch seems to get applied.

With a monkey patch:

```
module Net
  class HTTPGenericRequest
    def write_header(sock, ver, path)
      puts "monkey patched!"
      # patch stuff...
    end
  end
end

Service.new.make_request
# monkey patched!
```

With a refinement:

```
module NetHttpPatch
  refine Net::HTTPGenericRequest do
    def write_header(sock, ver, path)
      puts "refined!"
      # patch stuff...
    end
  end
end

class Service
  using NetHttpPatch
end

Service.new.make_request
# :(
```

UPDATE:

This seems to be similar scope wise? Obviously more complex things are happening when net/http makes a request does it lose scope then?

```
module TimeExtension
  refine Fixnum do
    def hours
      self * 60
    end
  end
end

class Service
  using TimeExtension

  def one_hour
    puts 1.hours
  end
end

puts Service.new.one_hour
# 60
```

UPDATE UPDATE:

nvm, I see what's happening now :) have to keep your brain from mixing `using` up with how mixins work.

```
module TimeExtension
  refine Fixnum do
    def hours
      self * 60
    end
  end
end

class Foo
  def one_hour
    puts 1.hours
  end
end


class Service
  using TimeExtension

  def one_hour
    puts 1.hours
  end

  def another_hour
    Foo.new.one_hour
  end
end

puts Service.new.one_hour
# 60
puts Service.new.another_hour
# undefined method `hours' for 1:Fixnum (NoMethodError)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this a namespace issue?

It is a scope issue. [Refinements are lexically scoped](http://ruby-doc.org/core/doc/syntax/refinements_rdoc.html#label-Scope):

```
class Service
  using NetHttpPatch
  # Refinement is in scope here
end

# different lexical scope, Refinement is not in scope here

class Service
  # another different lexical scope, Refinement is *not* in scope here!
end
```

Originally, there was only `main::using`, which was script-scoped, i.e. the Refinement was in scope for the entire remainder of the script. `Module#using` came later, it scopes the Refinement to the lexical class definition body.

Comment: Updated the question with a more simple example, which does add the refinement when called from a new instance, might be missing something :)